# How do I get c pointer for JNA structure array

Tags: java, c, binding, jna

structTable is a pointer to MyStruct

```
MyStruct structs[3]; 
myobject.structTable = &structs[0]
myobject.structTableSize = 3;
```

How do I do the same in java with JNA?

Answer (score 0):

Vague question.  Vague answer.  This should work if you're creating a new/empty structure.

```
MyStruct struct = new MyStruct();
MyStruct[] structs = (MyStruct[]) struct.toArray(3);
myobject.structTable = structs; // Java Object pointing to structure array
long cPointer = Pointer.nativeValue(structs[0].getPointer()); // C pointer address
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the pointer of first element in the empty array, also structs.getPointer() isn't a method?

Comment: Empty array? It has 3 elements?    Sorry, should have been `structs[0].getPointer()` if you really need the native C pointer value (but that's hardly ever required in Java for anything).

Comment: the library that I am trying to map said it needs empty structTable but it found structTable that is not empty

Comment: Those details would be useful in your question. With the limited code you've posted, I've answered all that I can.